# Find all chlidren for more parents

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using hierarchyid in my table (SQL Server 2008 R2). I have to find all descendants for more than one node. My result of parents looks like:

```
| Parent     | 
|:-----------|
| 0x6CB0AC   |
| 0x6CB180   |           
| 0x6CB181   |      
| 0x6CB141   |        
|            |
```

How should I write the query which will return all descendants for each of those parents ?

Design of my table:

```
ID: HierarchyId
Name: varchar(100)
Surname: varchar(100)
```

Comment: Use a recursive CTE as explained here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: Why a recursive CTE? Use hierarchyid.IsDescendantOf method!

Comment: @JesúsLópez - IsDescendantOf method works only on one node. I need to find children of more than one node - my result is data set with many nodes.

Comment: @FrenkyB. You can combine IsDescenandOf with exists as I done in my answer. Did you look at it? It finds descendants of several parents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the table name is Tree, here you have the query:

```
;WITH P AS
(
    SELECT CAST(ParentId AS hierarchyid) AS ParentId
    FROM 
        (VALUES (0x6CB0AC), (0x6CB180)) 
        AS Parents(ParentId)
)
SELECT *
FROM 
    Tree T
WHERE
    EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM P
        WHERE T.Id.IsDescendantOf(P.ParentId) = 1
   )
```

EDIT: I removed the last two binary strings because they are not valid hierarchyid's

EDIT: here you have an example that shows you descendants of 1.1 and 1.2, with hierarchyid 0x5AC0 and 0x6AC0.

```
CREATE TABLE Tree
(
    Id hierarchyid PRIMARY KEY,
    Name varchar(100)

);


INSERT INTO Tree(Id, Name) VALUES
('/1/', '1'), 
('/1/1/', '1.1'),
('/1/1/1/', '1.1.1'),
('/1/1/2/', '1.1.2'),
('/2/', '2'), 
('/2/1/', '2.1'),
('/2/1/1/', '2.1.1'),
('/2/1/2/', '2.1.2');

WITH Ids AS
(
    SELECT CAST(Id as hierarchyid) AS Id 
    FROM (VALUES (0x5AC0), (0x6AC0)) T(Id)
)
SELECT T.*
FROM
    Tree T
WHERE
    EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM Ids
        WHERE T.Id.IsDescendantOf(Ids.Id) = 1
   )
```

Result:

```
+--------+-------+
|   Id   | Name  |
+--------+-------+
| 0x5AC0 | 1.1   |
| 0x5AD6 | 1.1.1 |
| 0x5ADA | 1.1.2 |
| 0x6AC0 | 2.1   |
| 0x6AD6 | 2.1.1 |
| 0x6ADA | 2.1.2 |
+--------+-------+
```

Notice that IsDescendantOf consider Parent as its own descendant.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select parent.ID, child.*
From dbo.YourTable as child
Join dbo.YourTable as parent
   On child.HierarchyColumn.IsDescendantOf(parent.HierarchyColumn) = 1
```